# best practice for working with deeply nested json data in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to create an csv file from this deeply nested json structure:

```
{
            "id": "12345678",
            "name": "BOOGIEMAN",
            "account_id": "1234567",
            "campaign_id": "123",
            "attribution_spec": [
                {
                    "event_type": "CLICK_THROUGH",
                    "window_days": 1
                }
            ],
            "bid_amount": 14000,
            "bid_info": {
                "REACH": 14000
            },
            "bid_strategy": "LOWEST_COST_WITH_BID_CAP",
            "pacing_type": [
                "standard"
            ],
            "promoted_object": {
                "application_id": "123456",
                "custom_event_type": "PURCHASE",
                "object_store_url": "https://itunes.apple.com/app/123456"
            },
            "recurring_budget_semantics": true,
            "review_feedback": "[]",
            "source_adset": {
                "id": "1234567"
            },
            "source_adset_id": "1234567",
            "start_time": "2019-12-12T17:10:20+0100",
            "status": "ACTIVE",
            "targeting": {
                "age_max": 65,
                "age_min": 20,
                "custom_audiences": [
                    {
                        "id": "1234567",
                        "name": "SAMPLE_NAME"
                    }
                ],
                "exclusions": {
                    "interests": [
                        {
                            "id": "123",
                            "name": "Teens Fashion"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "456",
                            "name": "Boomerang (TV channel)"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "7895",
                            "name": "Boomerang"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "123",
                            "name": "Nickelodeon Games and Sports for Kids"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "555",
                            "name": "Disney Interactive"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "123123",
                            "name": "Disney Channel"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "6456",
                            "name": "CBBC (TV channel)"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "124124",
                            "name": "Nickelodeon"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "34653254",
                            "name": "Cartoon Network"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "12414",
                            "name": "The Children's Channel"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "325623",
                            "name": "International Children's Games"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "325234",
                            "name": "Children's television series"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "6324535",
                            "name": "Teens Only ღ"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "6013742415695",
                            "name": "Books for Kids"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "targeting_optimization": "none",
                "user_device": [
                    "iPad",
                    "iPhone"
                ],
                "user_os": [
                    "iOS_ver_9.0_and_above"
                ]
            },
            "updated_time": "2019-12-20T13:04:20+0100",
            "use_new_app_click": false
        }
```

I tried using the Pandas for Python library, and I am able to unpack the data up 1 level, but I would like to unpack this data as much as possible so that there are not any lists or objects.

I guess this question revolves more around what should be the best practice to work with some data like this?

Sample output?:
[image]

Comment: Csv files by definition have just 1 level. How would you expect such a file to look? I would understand if you wanted to create several csv files.

Comment: @uri I'm guessing that for every level of data, you have to create a new row and account for all levels. So if I'm saying this correctly, let's say there is 1 record with 30 columns total, and column 29 has 2 objects and column 30 has 5 objects. To account for all levels, you would need to create 10 records? I guess end goal being as flat as possible in one csv file

Comment: @dataviews I'm not sure I understand your explanation, can you expand on it? _I guess this question revolves more around what should be the best practice to work with some data like this?_ That's going to be difficult to answer without any information on the kind of work to perform.

Comment: @AMC check this picture out: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOlCD.png

Comment: @AMC I basically want to flatten this data to 0 levels

Comment: @dataviews Right, so how do you intend to do that? Why do you need to flatten it, what for?

Comment: @AMC that's what im asking for help on...maybe it isn't possible with this data? Just a moment, im making an excel layout of what i want to achieve

Comment: @dataviews Depending on the format of the data (we only have one example, so we can't generalize), it'll be more or less difficult.

Comment: @AMC check out the image i posted. I only took a few elements from my data to show as a sample, to cover all possible levels. But I think this is what needs to happen to achieve level of 0?

Comment: Aaah, I see what you did. Well, if the format works for you, that could do.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I just use the csv library. https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/csv.html

Here is a detailed article explaining it's use in this case. 
http://blog.appliedinformaticsinc.com/how-to-parse-and-convert-json-to-csv-using-python/